# How to find the largest integer among an infinite number of integers in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int res;
    int max;
    int i;
    int Maximum; 

    for (i = 0 ; i < res; i++)
    {
      res = scanf("%d",&max);
      if( res != 1 ) return 0;
      if(max > Maximum)
      {
        Maximum = max;
      }
    }
    printf("%d",&Maximum  );
    return 0;
    }
```

Hi guys, I don't understand why Maximum prints out an obscene high number. 
Just want a reason why, not something to hold my hand, for I really want to learn this language, I know Java mostly so what's happening here?

Comment: Initialize `Maximum` to something very low to start (e.g. `INT_MIN` of `limits.h`).

Comment: Infinite, I think this word does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: Formally that is not possible: if there are an _infinite_ number of integers, there will always be one that is larger than the one you have found already.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Oh really, what about an infinite batch of zeros?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, what about the *negative* integers?  There is an infinite number of them, but there is none greater than -1.

Comment: @undur-gomgor, without wanting to start a battle of wits, you will never know this as you have to keep reading and reading.... So at least there _might_ always be one larger than the largest you have encountered (even if the largest one is still zero).

Comment: @John-Bolinger, see my reply to Undur Gongor.

Answer (score 1):

**1.**   No need to pass address of integer variable.Else right now you are passing wrong argument to `%d` causes *undefined behaviour*.

```
 printf("%d",&Maximum  );
             ^ remove &
```

To print value of `Maximum`-

```
 printf("%d", Maximum);
```

**2.** `Maximum` *is unitialized in you program* , therefore ,comparing it without initialization is incorrect.

```
int Maximum;                 // unintialized variable
```

Initialize it before using -

```
int Maximum=INT_MIN;         // header <limits.h>
```

**3.** This loop of yours is not infinite. It will just iterate for `1` time -

```
for (i = 0 ; i < res; i++)
{
    //your code
}
```

Instead use an infinite loop -

```
for(; ;){                              // or while(1)
 //your code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize `Maximum` to some value which is lowest for all the possible input values.

   e.g. If input is guaranteed to contain only the positive integers then

   `Maximum = -1;`

   Or better use `Maximum = INT_MIN;` as pointed in comments. For that you'll need to include `<limits.h>` header file in your program.
2. `printf("%d",&Maximum  );`

   This is wrong. This will print the address of `Maximum`.

   Use `printf("%d", Maximum);`
3. `for (i = 0 ; i < res; i++)`

   `res` is not initialized! For an infinite numbers you'll want to make this loop infinite as `while(1)` or `for( ; ; )`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize some value for the variable `Maximum`.

```
Maximum=0; // you can assign any value.
```

Then You have to change this line,

```
printf("%d",&Maximum  );
```

into

```
printf("%d",Maximum  );
```

`&Maximum` will give the address of the integer variable. While getting the input from `scanf` only we have to give like that.

Answer (score 0):

Because the program cannot know whether user will input only negative numbers, only positive numbers, or both, initializing "max" (or min) to a random number (such as zero) with the hope that it would "definitely" be maximum / minimum during the course of the execution, is likely to give erroneous results at some point.

The following is a simplistic approach that solely relies on user input, without trying to include any additional header files for absolute min / max values. It assumes the first provided input as "max", and if any subsequent entry surpasses that value, max is reset.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
        int num, max;
        int first_input = 1;

        while(scanf("%d", &num) != EOF){
            if(first_input){
                max = num;
                first_input = 0;
            }
            else{
                if(max < num){
                    max = num;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("\n Maximum of the scanned numbers is: %d", max);
        return 0;
    }
```

The program will continue running until the user terminates the input by hitting Ctrl+D / Ctrl+Z.